# What statues are Dandy2Men based off of?

Tags: sekko-boys

In episode 7: Civil War Brewing, we are introduced to Dandy 2 Men.

There is **Man of Conviction: Brutus**:

[image]

and **Unexpected King of Comedy: Molière:**

[image]

I'm familiar with the character of Brutus, but not Molière.

Are these real life statues, [like those of the Sekko boys?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28841/what-are-the-original-sculptures-of-the-sekko-boys)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Brutus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Junius_Brutus_the_Younger)

> Marcus Junius Brutus was a politician of the late Roman Republic. He is best known in modern times for taking a leading role in the assassination of Julius Caesar.

[This bust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brutus_%28Michelangelo%29) as created by Michelangelo and can be found in the Bargello museum in Florence

[image]

---

### [Molière](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moli%C3%A8re)

Molière is a french playwriter. He is famous in France for his pieces of theatre he wrote.

As a side note, Molière **is** really famous in France. We sometimes use the expression "*The Molière's tongue*" to refer to the French langage

The statue of Sekko Boys is based on a real-life statue, which can be found at the Louvre, in France.

[image]